# Attempting to move Image File, throwing FileNotFoundException for output directory

Tags: java, android, file, io, directory

I'm trying to find a simple way to take an image with a known path and folder, and move it to a new folder in the gallery. When calling this method, bucketName is provided by selecting from a list of bucketNames that are queried from android Images MediaStore.

The problem I'm getting is that the try block is never executed, no matter what that bucketName ends up being, because when trying to initiate the OutputStream, it says that the file is not found and jumping to the catch block. However, I am creating a file at the destination location, so I'm not sure why it's saying this. I've been looking for alternative solutions, however almost every recommendation on here seems to be to use this method, or TransferFrom or TransferTo (Which also yield the same problem).

Edit: I should note, I check for Write_External_Storage perms every time the app is opened.

```
public void moveImage(int position, String bucketname)
{
    String oldPath = imgList.get(position).getImage_path();
    String newPath = oldPath.replace(imgList.get(position).getImage_bucket(), bucketname);

    Log.i("index", oldPath);
    Log.i("index", newPath);

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try
    {
        File newFile = new File(newPath);
        if (!newFile.exists())
        {
            boolean result = newFile.mkdirs();
            Log.i("index", "file didnt exist");
        }

        Log.i("index", "file exists");
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(oldPath));
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        inputStream = null;

        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;
        Log.i("index", "successful");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("index", "unsuccessful");
    }

    //String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?";
    //String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(imgList.get(position).getImage_path())};
    //ctx.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, selection, selectionArgs);

    imgList.remove(position);

    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    //intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(newFile));
    //ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Here is the stack Trace I'm getting - newFile is said to exist, the old and new paths to the file are printed

```
I/index: /storage/emulated/0/Download/retrowave_80_s_bg_by_rafael_de_jongh-d9wsq5j.png
I/index: /storage/emulated/0/Camera/retrowave_80_s_bg_by_rafael_de_jongh-d9wsq5j.png
I/index: file exists
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Camera/retrowave_80_s_bg_by_rafael_de_jongh-d9wsq5j.png (Is a directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kyler.bugout.MediaServer.moveImage(MediaServer.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kyler.bugout.MainActivity$4.onBucketClick(MainActivity.java:383)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kyler.bugout.MoveImageDialogFragment$1.onClick(MoveImageDialogFragment.java:44)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1119)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3126)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4041)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
I/index: unsuccessful
```

Comment: `and move it to a new folder in the gallery. `. No. Not at all. You are copying a file to the file system. It has nothing to do with the Gallery or Photos app on your device.

Comment: @greenapps Do you have a recommendation for a better way to do this?
After implementing your solution and uncommenting that part of the code that lets the MediaStore scan the new file, It does create a new folder and copy the image over to it... however it also creates that folder regardless of whether or not one with the same name already exists.

Comment: Impossible. So then you would have two folders with the same name!? Impossible. Please show your code in an extra code block.

Comment: @greenapps Two folders with the same name, one was missing the DCIM path though because of the way I'm setting the new path. I fixed it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (!newFile.exists())
    {
        boolean result = newFile.mkdirs();
        Log.i("index", "file didnt exist");
    }
```

This creates a directory `retrowave_80_s_bg_by_rafael_de_jongh-d9wsq5j.png` (which is actually mentioned in your exception). You should change the block to

```
    if (!newFile.exists())
    {
        boolean result = newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        Log.i("index", "file didnt exist");
    }
```

Comment: I get a can't resolve method for this. Should I use something like new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs(); I'm also not getting a log for "file doesn't exist" though, so this code is never being called

Comment: `if (!newFile.exists())`. That should be `if (!newFile.getParentFile().exists()) if (!newFile.getParentFile.mkdirs()) return;`.

Comment: @KyleR I fixed it. Should have been `getParentFile`

Comment: @greenapps You might be right but it might also be correct the way it is if the file can already exist

Comment: No. Because if the file does not exist then still the directory can exist. And then mkdirs() should not be called.

Comment: Both of these methods seem to work - both if (!newFile.exists()) and if (!newFile.getParentFile().exists()) then using the getparentfile method. They interestingly create a duplicate folder called "Camera" for example... even though a folder named "Camera" already exists.